# How to specify the type of a list in Drools 5.5?

Tags: java, generics, drools, rules

Our rules are based on v4.x now we are migrating to v5.5. It seems this version is type safe so the following code won't work properly:

```
$contractualBalances : ArrayList() from accountService.getContractualBalances($id, $cmounts)
```

now when we have this forall statement, it doesn't work because the ArrayList above doesn't specified the type:

```
ContractualBalance() from $contractualBalances
```

Can anyone please help me how to specify the type. I tried to use ArrayList() but no luck

Thanks

Comment: You mean the type of a list (the implementing class) or the generic type of the list (the type of its content)? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem:

```
$contractualBalances : ContractualBalance() from accountService.getContractualBalances($id, $cmounts)
```